# PySide2, QTableWidget, data to python object

Tags: python, pyside2

I am converting a tool to Pyside2 and am using a QTableWidget. I need to retrieve the cell data, but am having an issue with understanding if I need to cast it to a python object (.toPyObject in PyQt4).

In my old version table query, I had:

```
item_text = item.text()
item_data = item.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()
```

Where item_text is the retrieval of the cell. I have looked through the docs and online, but have not found out if or what the PySide2 equivalent is. I saw some info relating to QVariant, but unclear if that is a substitute to use or if I have just overlooked something in the PySide2 docs.

Comment: Why did you edit the post? Its nothing to do with PySide, I am using PySide2. Also, is putting thanks not allowed now?

Comment: The question is exactly the same. It was edited (not by me) to include the tag PySide and removed two lines, one said pointers welcome and the other said thanks. Why did that need changing?

Comment: But I am using PySide2, which has differences. If I wanted advice on PySide, I would have asked for it. I came here for advice on coding, not a lesson in grammar and dont expect post to be changed by someone who assumes it needs updating. Thats the main issue with this site, too many snobs and not enough help. I will go elsewhere for advice.

Comment: As stated, the question is the same except for the removal of two lines, and the question is valid in every other sense. I know you did not edit it. Just fed up of not getting answers on here and having post tweaked for no reason.

Comment: I tried to post feedback, but my account was stopped from posting and I could not fit the reply in as I wanted to show the working method, but the reply by you was also removed, so I had no way to respond.

Comment: You removed your answer as if you are punishing a naughty child. So who has the bad attitude? Grow up.

Comment: As I said above, I TRIED to post the working method, but couldnt because my account was stopped form posting and the feedback was too long for a comment. I was posting the code I have to show that I tried what you suggested and it didnt work as expected. How else am I going to give that feedback?

Comment: Well, I do not come on here often enough to know all the strict rules of conversing with someone, so my site etiquette is not as advanced as others. Im being dismissed for not knowing all the rules? I hardly see anything in my previous comments that are of the level of complaint that you assume they are, perhaps you could point to the comments that are so hurtful.

Comment: I am asking you where the complaint is. I do not need anyone else as I am directly talking to you. You are the one who states my comments are complaints, so I will ask again. WHer is the complaint in my comments?

Comment: My comments are questions. I asked why the post was edited. The only thing I can see is the use of snobs, but in my experience, getting a response is difficult and previously have had posts removed or altered without any helpful input. The rest of the comments do not contain any level of complaint, just questions. If you believe a question is a complaint, then anything asked could be a complaint.

Comment: Well, I did point that out above, and its not a complaint but an observation. If it was a complaint, I would have asked for it to be sorted out. But, I guess that your definition of complaint and mine are different. Its by the by though as I dont have the information I want (or had), so will have to find it elsewhere I guess.